# Xamarin.Forms: Get PropertyInfo from Binding information

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, system.reflection

In XAML I define some elements, e.g. ToolbarItems:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.ViewModels" 
             x:DataType="vm:MyViewModel"
             x:Class="MyNamespace.Views.MyPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}" >
...
    <ToolbarItem x_Name="ThisItem" Text="Some text" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="Some parameter" />
```

In Code Behind I need the `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo` of property `SomeCommand` defined in XAML by the Binding information.

Is this possible?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In the toolbar menu I offer several display modes which require different ViewModels derived from the same base class. Some of the ToolbarMenuItems use a command (here "SomeCommand") of ths base class.
In the moment, I re-assign this command property of the current ViewModel in code behind. This would be a solution that works. However I would prefer not to have the same information twice - in XAML and code behind. If I had the PropertyInfo of this property I could get the value of this property by reflection.

Comment: `However I would prefer not to have the same information twice - in XAML and code behind. ` Why would you get the same information twice? If you use Command, you can get the Command Parameter by the passed object.

Comment: Now I decided to remove the Command assignment in XAML and define it in Code Behind only.
It would have been tricky to obtain the PropertyInfo for "SomeCommand" from the XAML Binding information and use it for the different ViewModels.

Comment: That is, is your problem solved? Congrats, can you share your solution so that others will benefit from your answer as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to remove the Command assignment in XAML and define it in Code Behind only. It would have been tricky to obtain the PropertyInfo for "SomeCommand" from the XAML Binding information and use it for the different ViewModels.